# Spark-Scala Convert String of Numbers to Double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to make a dense Vector out of a string. But first, i need to convert to a double. How do i get it in double format?

```
[-- feature: string (nullable = false)]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1kWz.png

I have tried:

```
val new_col = df.withColumn("feature", df("feature").cast(DoubleType))
```

But, it results in a column of Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

val df = Seq(
  "-1,-1,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0",
  "7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,",
  "12.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,12.0,12.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,12.0",
  "-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,5.0,9.0,9.0"
).toDF("feature")

def stringToVector = udf ( (s: String) =>
  new DenseVector(s.split(",").map(_.toDouble))
)

df.withColumn("feature", stringToVector($"feature")).
  show(false)
// +---------------------------------------------------+
// |feature                                            |
// +---------------------------------------------------+
// |[-1.0,-1.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0]|
// |[7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0]          |
// |[12.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,12.0,12.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,12.0]|
// |[-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,5.0,9.0,9.0]   |
// +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> first, i need to convert to a double. How do i get it in double format?

You can simply use `split` *inbuilt function* and cast to `Array[Double]` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val new_col = df.withColumn("feature", split(df("feature"), ",").cast("array<double>"))
```

which should give you

```
root
 .....
 .....
 |-- feature: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 .....
 .....
```

I hope the answer is helpful